# Problem with slopes.

Tags: fractions

I currently have a slope that looks like this:

$\frac{-5}{10}$

However, I need to bring it down to it's lowest terms, so I divided the numerator and denominator by -5 and I got:

$\frac{1}{-2}$

Although, if I divide it by 5 I get:

$\frac{-1}{2}$

Would it matter which answer I chose for the slope?

Also, I've been told that a slope should be in integers, is this true?

Comment: Note that $\frac{-1}{2}=\frac{1}{-2}$ as you have just shown. This is as $\frac{-1}{-1}=1$, so notice multiplying either fraction by this yields the other, but this is multiplying by $1$, so this does not change the number.

Comment: It is a fairly common convention to try to make denominators positive.

Comment: Negative slope means the curve is moving in opposite directions on x- and y-axes -- towards negative on y-axis while the value on x-axis increases. A negative number is negative, doesn't matter where the '-' sign is.

Comment: Anyone who tells you that a slope should be in whole numbers should have their Mathematician's license revoked. Inform the Math Cabal (shh. It's supposed to be a secret) of the individual and they'll handle it, usually with extremely messy results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a style question. There is no difference between having the negative sign in the top, bottom, or out in front of the whole thing and they can all be correct. Personally, I put the negative sign out in front of the entire fraction. As for whole numbers, as long as both the numerator and the denominator are integers, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not matter so long as you divide the entire fraction by the same number. Slope = Rise/run. Try graphing both, you'll get the same line.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please don't bump old posts unless you have discovered an innovative solution that has not been said.

Comment: Apologies. Thanks for the heads-up.